Do mountains shield part of the heat when sun is still visible?
I noticed temperatures peak and then start to drop around two hours earlier in a valley surrounded by mountains compared to plains. Temperature peaks when the sun  is still high in the sky, well before it goes down behind the mountain. I wonder if this is because even if the sun has not yet gone down fully, in later hours we only get part of the light rays, because some of them are behind, not reaching the valley (i.e., the shadow forming at the bottom of the mountain), meaning less energy (and therefore heat) comes in. Is this correct, or not even close?
